# macOS Mojave hibernatemode 25 Dark Wake

Tags: macos, encryption, macos-mojave, filevault, hibernate-mode

I have set hibernate mode to 25 and the standby time to 0 in macOS Mojave. Now my idea is that the Mac goes to deep sleep (no power to RAM). Most of the time it works; if I open the lid I see this screen:
[Picture: wake up from deep sleep](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkXXf.png)

But sometimes I have to press the power button to start the Mac. Either it starts as I would have turn it off before. Or (more often) it starts for a second (with start sound) and then turns black and starts again (again start sound).

I read something about "dark wake". So may be the problem is, that the Mac wakes up. But I don't know how to prevent that.

Any ideas? Or maybe a better setup to secure the system (in-fact prevent the encryption key from FileVault to be in the RAM when I close the lid)?

---

My setup is:

- I have one user only for Disc encryption (other users are deleted with: `sudo fdesetup remove -user username`)
- DestroyFVKeyOnStandby = 1
- standby = 0

```
~$> pmset -g
System-wide power settings:
 DestroyFVKeyOnStandby      1
Currently in use:
 standbydelaylow      0
 standby              0
 halfdim              1
 hibernatefile        /var/vm/sleepimage
 gpuswitch            2
 powernap             0
 disksleep            0
 standbydelayhigh     0
 sleep                0 (sleep prevented by cloudd, cloudd, sharingd)
 autopoweroffdelay    28800
 hibernatemode        25
 autopoweroff         1
 ttyskeepawake        1
 displaysleep         0
 highstandbythreshold 50
 acwake               0
 lidwake              1
```

Comment: This question is not about programming. Asking this question at [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com) might help.

Comment: I did that. Thanks!